# SYS_open to SYS_write in x86-64 assembly

Tags: x86-64

So I have two functions.  One opens a file and returns the file descriptor via reference.  There other takes that file descriptor and writes to that file.

```
    mov rax, sys_open  ;open file
    mov rdi, filename  ;name of file
    mov rsi, read_only ;access permission
    syscall            ;system call
```

(returns valid file descriptor in rax)

In the next function:

```
    mov rax, sys_write
    mov rdi, qword[file_descriptor]
    mov rsi, string
    mov rdx, qword[length]
    syscall
```

this code gives me an error [-9] returned into rax.  Is there anything wrong with the block of code that is fundamentally wrong?

Comment: You are trying to write when you opened as read only?

Comment: Error number -9 suggests a bad file number

Comment: You don't show how you defined `file_descriptor` and `length` or anythign else. The code suggests you are reading those values as 8 byte values. Did you declare them as qwords?

Comment: Ok thank you I had a basic understanding wrong.  I thought we want to have read_only access when opening files to get descriptors, and the sys_write system call had write permission by default.  Thanks again

Comment: Run your program under `strace` to see the args and return values your code is actually sending/receiving from system calls.  Then look up the error codes in the man page for the relevant syscall.  See also the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).